# Rendering other form by ajax causes its view state to be lost, how do I add this back?

Tags: ajax, forms, jsf, jsf-2, viewstate

I have

```html
<h:form>
    <h:commandLink action="#{my_fake_ajax_link}">
        <h:outputText value="Link" />
        <f:ajax render=":mydiv" />
    </h:commandLink>
</h:form>

<h:panelGroup layout="block" id="mydiv">
    <h:form>
        <h:commandLink action="#{mybean.delete(0)}">
            <h:outputText value="Here" />
            <f:ajax render="@form" />
        </h:commandLink>
    </h:form>
</h:panelGroup>
```

When I click once on "my_fake_ajax_link", then I have to click twice on "delete" link. This is only an example. I don't have this real case. I have multiple forms on a page and I can't just add all of them in a single form.

I checked what the problem is and it is:

- When you click on "my_fake_ajax_link", the `mydiv` refreshs with ajax as it should.
- ViewState of the refreshed form on ajax is missing.

How can I add the ViewState? How can I make it work without using only one form? This looks like an JSF bug to me. I don't want to refresh that div automatically with

```
jQuery("#mydiv").load(document.location.href);
```

but I will in my worst case possible.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is a known problem in the auto-included `jsf.js` library of JSF which handles ajax responses. See also [JSF spec issue 790](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES_SPEC_PUBLIC-790) which is fixed in the upcoming JSF 2.3. In the meanwhile, with JSF 2.0/2.1/2.2, you have to explicitly specify the ID of the other `<h:form>` inside the `render` attribtue to trigger proper addition of the view state.

```html
<h:form>
    <h:commandLink action="#{my_fake_ajax_link}">
        <h:outputText value="Link" />
        <f:ajax render=":mydiv :mydivForm" />
    </h:commandLink>
</h:form>

<h:panelGroup layout="block" id="mydiv">
    <h:form id="mydivForm">
        <h:commandLink action="#{mybean.delete(0)}">
            <h:outputText value="Here" />
            <f:ajax render="@form" />
        </h:commandLink>
    </h:form>
</h:panelGroup>
```

No, this does not cause any overhead or markup duplication in the ajax response. Alternatively, use [OmniFaces `fixviewstate.js`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/scripts/FixViewState).

#### See also:

- [Communication in JSF 2.0 - Ajax rendering of content which contains another form](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#AjaxRenderingOfContentWhichContainsAnotherForm)
- [h:commandButton/h:commandLink does not work on first click, works only on second click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11408130/hcommandbutton-hcommandlink-does-not-work-on-first-click-works-only-on-second)

Comment: thank you a lot!!! I didn't find that link on google.. even after a long search...

Comment: It's a shame this hasn't made its way into JSF 2.2. Let's wait another year or two for having it fixed...

Comment: @mel: OmniFaces to the rescue: http://showcase.omnifaces.org/scripts/FixViewState

Answer (score 1):

Workaround for that:

First you need to set an `onevent` handler for the button that sends the ajax request:

```
<h:form id="newComment">
    <h:commandButton id="saveNewComment" action="#{postBean.actionSaveNewCommentAjax}" value="#{rb['speichern']}">
        <f:ajax execute="@form" render=":commentsBox" onevent="function(data) { fixOtherFormsViewState(data, 'newComment') }" />
    </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

Then you need to declare this javascript methods that will take the correct viewState value and add it to all forms which doesn't have it:

```
<h:outputScript>
function fixOtherFormsViewState(data, goodFormId) {
    if (data.status != "success") {
        return;
    }

    var viewState = jQuery("#" + goodFormId + " input[name='javax.faces.ViewState']").val();
    jQuery("form:not(:contains(input[name='javax.faces.ViewState']))").each(function (idx, elem) {
        var form = jQuery(elem);
        var input = jQuery("&lt;input type='hidden' name='javax.faces.ViewState' /&gt;").val(viewState);
        form.append(input);
    });
}
</h:outputScript>
```