# Primefaces ajax call in viewstate

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, viewstate

I need to toggle the display between two panels on the web page. Initially first panel with p:commandButton "First" will be displayed. Click on First button will send ajax request and display second panel with p:commandButton "Second". Click on "Second" button display "first panel. But, second panel viewstate is not updated, so p:commandButton "Second" can not fire an event.

```
<h:form id="firstForm" >
<h:panelGroup id="filterPanel" rendered="#{not filter.accepted}" >
<div id="menu">
<p:commandButton value="First" action="#{filter.action1}" update=":firstForm" >
</p:commandButton>
</div>
</h:panelGroup>

<h:panelGroup id="reportPanel" rendered="#{filter.accepted}" >
<div id="menu2">
<p:commandButton value="Second" action="#{filter.action2}" update=":firstForm">
</p:commandButton>
</div>
</h:panelGroup>
</h:form>
```

Bean code:

```
private boolean accepted;
public void action1(){
System.out.println("Filter Button");
accepted = true;
}

public void action2(){
System.out.println("Report Button");
accepted = false;
}

public boolean isAccepted() {
System.out.println(accepted);
return accepted;
}
```

First panel p:commandButton "First" calls action1 and prints "Filter Button". Second panel p:commandButton "Second" won't call action2 function, since its viewstate is not available. Is there any solution.

I went through the similar page, it did not work for me either
[JSF2: Form ajax action makes another form's view state to be lost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11164361/jsf2-form-ajax-action-makes-another-forms-view-state-to-be-lost)

Thanks

KDB

Comment: How exactly did you conclude that the view state is absent? Please come with proof. I'm asking this because this is strange based on the code/information provided so far. You've only one form here, not two. It's more likely that this problem is caused because the bean is put in request scope instead of view scope.

Comment: BalusC, you are right. The bean was in request scope. Changed the bean to ViewScoped. Thanks for the suggestions. KDB