# Why PostConstruct method is called several times inside an RichFaces 4.3 component with a ViewScoped?

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, richfaces, view-scope, postconstruct

I 'm facing a problem with JSF 2.2, richfaces 4.3.2 on Tomcat 7 .
My page is annoted `ViewScoped`.
I display a first form. When i change the value and select a specific one , i display by ajax a `rich:panel` element inside an `a4j:outputPanel`.
Inside this `a4j:outputPanel` and `rich:panel` component, i have a `h:commandButton` who execute the forms.
I want to retrieve messages error for the form if the fields are empty for example (or other stuffs)

But when i click `h:commandButton`, the view is re instancied and `@postcontruct` method is re executed. It should be executed one time only in the view scope, am i wrong ?

I don't want the view to be reactualised, i want keep the `ajaxoutputPanel` displayed when i click the `h:commandButton` inside.(and i want to see the `h:messages` next to my forms fields...not much asking :-) )

I read about some [bug](http://osdir.com/ml/java-jsf-richfaces-issues/2011-12/msg00449.html)... is there a way to change this behavior without passing to SessionScoped for example.

Thanks dudes.

```
    <fieldset>

    <h:form>

        <h:panelGrid columns="3">

            <h:outputText value ="Nom de l'étude : "></h:outputText> 
            <h:inputText id="study_name" value="#{analyse.study_name}"   size="20" required="true"  label="Nom de l'étude" />
            <h:message for="study_name" style="color:red" />

            <h:outputText value ="Analyse : "> </h:outputText> 
            <h:selectOneMenu  id = "analyse" value="#{analyse.analyse_type}">
            <f:selectItems value="#{analyse.analyse_type2Value}" />
                  <f:ajax execute="analyse" render=":ajaxOutputPanelAnalyse"  /> 
            </h:selectOneMenu>

         </h:panelGrid>

    </h:form>

</fieldset>

    <a4j:outputPanel id="ajaxOutputPanelAnalyse" layout="block" ajaxRendered="true"  >

    <rich:panel  id="richPanelAnalyse"  rendered="#{analyse.analyse_type == 'NGS' and request.isUserInRole('ROLE_ADMIN_PROFILER_NGS')}" >

        <h:form id ="NGS_form" >

            <h:panelGrid columns="4">

                <h:outputText value ="Run # :"> </h:outputText> 
                <h:inputText id="run_number" value="# {analyse.run_number}" size="20" required="true" label="Run" />
                <h:message for="run_number" style="color:red" />
                <h:outputText></h:outputText>


            </h:panelGrid>



                 <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{analyse.addAnalyse}"/>


            </h:form>

    </rich:panel>




  </a4j:outputPanel>
```

In the bean...

```
@PostConstruct
public void setFlashParam(){

    System.out.println("POST CONSTRUCT MON POTE");

    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();


     return;
}

public String addAnalyse(){


    System.out.println("Kikou");

    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(" - Ajout de l'analyse ?"+" pour le patient ?"+" dans l'étude "+ study_name +" -"));


    return "pretty:home";

}
```

Comment: So, your submit button is outside of any form, which is incorrect. Can you also show bean definition and button's action method?

Comment: Nice shot but I just made a mistake when I copy the code. The submit is actually in the form. (I edited). For instance , button's action method is empty, it just print something...I'll post the bean but i don't think the problem is coming from the bean. It's a quite common bean 'annoted managedBean & ViewScoped) with getters and setters for the attributes in xhtml...And my postconstruct method just set flash parameters from faces context in bean attributes .

Comment: What do you return from your action method?

Comment: I return pretty:home ...i use prettyFaces style for navigation and i go to my home page.

Comment: Note if i remove rich:panel, f:ajax call inside first form, and a4j:outputPanel , the postconstruct method is call once...The bean is initialised once and the messages error of each form fields are well displayed. I think the problem is due to ajax stuff...

Comment: I think it's a bug ...but still not sure http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7807334/rendering-other-form-by-ajax-causes-its-view-state-to-be-lost-how-do-i-add-this

Answer (score 1):

Resolve thanks to this post from BalusC (as always) http://balusc.blogspot.fr/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#AjaxRenderingOfContentWhichContainsAnotherForm

**EDIT :** But it's no more working when you try to add an rich:fileupload neither with h:inputFile... It will displayed strange html code in a newly textarea when you click the button....It's weird...

```
           <rich:fileUpload  id="upload" fileUploadListener="#{analyse.test}"  acceptedTypes="bam,pdf,png" ontyperejected="alert('Seulement les fichiers avec l'extension bam et pdf sont acceptés.');" maxFilesQuantity="3">
                  <a4j:ajax event="uploadcomplete" execute="@none" render="upload" />        
            </rich:fileUpload>
```