# Why a View is reinstancied, when we click a commandButton displayed in richfaces component displayed after an ajax call?

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, richfaces, view-scope

Initially my question was : Does richfaces 4.3.4 support JSF 2.2 and ViewScoped?

But now the question is in the title.Thanks :)

I'm trying to solve this [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19793618/why-postconstruct-method-is-called-several-times-inside-an-richfaces-4-3-compone). Why a View is reinstancied, when you click a command button displayed in richfaces component displayed after an ajax call ?

It seems i'm not alone : [anotherLink], [anotherlink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7807334/rendering-other-form-by-ajax-causes-its-view-state-to-be-lost-how-do-i-add-this) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7807334/rendering-other-form-by-ajax-causes-its-view-state-to-be-lost-how-do-i-add-this).

Comment: Resolve thanks to http://balusc.blogspot.fr/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#AjaxRenderingOfContentWhichContainsAnotherForm

Answer (score 0):

Resolve thanks to [this](http://balusc.blogspot.fr/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#AjaxRenderingOfContentWhichContainsAnotherForm). 
Thanks BalusC.

**EDIT :** But it's no more working when you try to add an rich:fileupload neither with h:inputFile... It will displayed strange html code in a newly textarea ....It's weird...

```
           <rich:fileUpload  id="upload" fileUploadListener="#{analyse.test}"  acceptedTypes="bam,pdf,png" ontyperejected="alert('Seulement les fichiers avec l'extension bam et pdf sont acceptés.');" maxFilesQuantity="3">
                  <a4j:ajax event="uploadcomplete" execute="@none" render="upload" />        
            </rich:fileUpload>
```