# Render form only on button press

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2.2

I am trying to figure out how to render a form after pressing a button that is part of a different form. I have successfully done this with datatables with no problem but I need to render input fields this time. I am using the latest version of JSF with netbeans and bootfaces.

There is a boolean member of the bean `BookList` called `showAdd` which should determine if the form is rendered and the method `toggleShowAdd()` changes this value to the opposite of its current value.

Starting from the button to view the form:

```
<h:commandButton action="#{bookList.toggleShowAdd}" 
                                 value="Add to Inventory">
                    <f:ajax render=":addForm" />
               </h:commandButton>
            </h:form>

            <h:form id="addForm" rendered="#{bookList.showAdd}">
                <b:row>
                    <b:column span="1">ISBN:</b:column>
                    <b:column span="1">
                        <h:inputText binding="#{isbn}" />
                    </b:column>
                </b:row>
                <b:row>
                    <b:column span="1">Title:</b:column>
                    <b:column span="1">
                        <h:inputText binding="#{title}" />
                    </b:column>
                </b:row>
                <b:row>
                    <b:column span="1">Author:</b:column>
                    <b:column span="1">
                        <h:inputText binding="#{author}"/>
                    </b:column>
                </b:row>
                <b:row>
                    <b:column span="1">Price:</b:column>
                    <b:column span="1">
                        <h:inputText binding="#{price}" />
                    </b:column>
                </b:row>
                <b:row>
                    <b:column span="1">
                        <h:commandButton value="Add" 
                                     action="#{bookList.addToInventory(isbn, title, author, price)}">
                            <f:ajax render="@form :inventoryview" />
                        </h:commandButton>
                    </b:column>
                </b:row>
            </h:form>
```

Comment: What is the problem, please? Do not use multiple forms until/unless absolutely necessary. For this particular case see [this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7807401/1391249).

Comment: Your `<h:form/>` should not be part of your selective rendering logic. Use a panel of some sort instead

Comment: Oh I understand now. I did not know that multiple forms was a no-no.