# When does mojarra adds a naming container to the list of optional parameters?

Tags: jsf, rendering, jsf-2.2, mojarra, naming-containers

In the source of the class [AjaxBehaviorRenderer (line 260)](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.sun.faces/jsf-impl/2.2.12/com/sun/faces/renderkit/html_basic/AjaxBehaviorRenderer.java?av=f) there is a line that apparently appends the `NamingContainer` Id to the list of optional parameters of `mojarra.ab(...)`. I've never come across it so I'm curious as to when it is used:

```
RenderKitUtils.appendProperty(ajaxCommand, "com.sun.faces.namingContainerId", namingContainerId, true);
```

line 260

Comment: It's only interesting for portlet based apps (not servlet based apps). I can't exactly explain why and what it is used for (a portlet/liferay guy might), but the portlet specific feature is called "namespaced parameters". See e.g. https://web.liferay.com/web/meera.success/blog/-/blogs/liferay-requires-name-spaced-parameters Related issues: https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES_SPEC_PUBLIC-861 and https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-3031

Comment: @BalusC I'm putting your comment as answer. If you want to do it yourself just answer and I'll accept yours. I don't like having questions still open

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While working on [spec issue 790](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES_SPEC_PUBLIC-790) last week, which should solve a.o. [Rendering other form by ajax causes its view state to be lost, how do I add this back?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7807334), this was explained to me by Neil Griffin, a portlet guy.

It appears that portlets can have multiple JSF views rendering to the same HTML document, each with its own view state. In portlets, there's a special `UIViewRoot` instance which implements `NamingContainer`. During regular rendering, all forms, inputs and commands will have IDs and names prefixed with the view's own client ID. This will work fine during synchronous postbacks. The portlet can this way identify the exact view to restore.

However, during asynchronous postbacks, the `jsf.js` will create a bunch of additional ajax-specific request parameters such as `javax.faces.source`, `javax.faces.partial.event`, etc. Those request parameter names are not prefixed with the view's own client ID. Therefore the portlet cannot associate them with a specific view. Hence the [impl issue 3031](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-3031).

There was another problem of view state identifiers in ajax responses not being properly namespaced this way. Therefore the portlet implementation had to customize the partial response writer in the so-called "JSF bridge". This will be taken into account during implementing spec issue 790. Instead of sniffing a "portlet environment" as in current implementation, there will be checks on `UIViewRoot instanceof NamingContainer` which is more flexible and portlet-independent. The Mojarra-specific `com.sun.faces.namingContainerId` will also be removed. Instead, this value will be rendered to `<partial-response id="...">` so that the `jsf.js` can just extract from there.

All in all, not really important if you're only targeting servlet based environments.

Answer (score 0):

As per balusC comment :

> It's only interesting for portlet based apps (not servlet based apps).
>   I can't exactly explain why and what it is used for (a portlet/liferay
>   guy might), but the portlet specific feature is called "namespaced
>   parameters". See https://web.liferay.com/web/meera.success/blog/-/blogs/liferay-requires-name-spaced-parameters